# Pandas DateOffset, step back one day

Tags: date, pandas

I try to understand why

```
print(pd.Timestamp("2015-01-01") - pd.DateOffset(day=1))
```

does not result in

```
pd.Timestamp("2014-12-31")
```

I am using Pandas 0.18. I run within the CET timezone.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can check [`pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html):

> `*kwds`
> Temporal parameter that add to or replace the offset value.
> Parameters that add to the offset (like Timedelta):

> - years
> - months
> - weeks
> - days
> - hours
> - minutes
> - seconds
> - microseconds
> - nanoseconds

> Parameters that replace the offset value:

> - year
> - month
> - day
> - weekday
> - hour
> - minute
> - second
> - microsecond
> - nanosecond

---

```
print(pd.Timestamp("2015-01-01") - pd.DateOffset(days=1))
2014-12-31 00:00:00
```

Another solution:

```
print(pd.Timestamp("2015-01-01") - pd.offsets.Day(1))
2014-12-31 00:00:00
```

Also it is possible to subtract `Timedelta`:

```
print(pd.Timestamp("2015-01-01") - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))
```

Answer (score 11):

`pd.DateOffset(day=1)` works (ie no error is raised) because "**day**" is a valid parameter, as is "**days**".

Look at the below one: "**day**" resets the actual day, "**days**" adds to the original day.

> pd.Timestamp("2019-12-**25**") + pd.DateOffset(**day**=1)
>
> Timestamp('2019-12-**01** 00:00:00')
>
> pd.Timestamp("2019-12-**25**") + pd.DateOffset(**days**=1)
>
> Timestamp('2019-12-**26** 00:00:00')

Answer (score 3):

Day(d) and DateOffset(days=d) do not behave exactly the same when used on timestamps with timezone information (at least on pandas 0.18.0). It looks like DateOffset add 1 day while keeping the hour information while Day adds just 24 hours of elapsed time.

```
>>> # 30/10/2016 02:00+02:00 is the hour before the DST change
>>> print(pd.Timestamp("2016-10-30 02:00+02:00", tz="Europe/Brussels") + pd.offsets.Day(1))
2016-10-31 01:00:00+01:00
>>> print(pd.Timestamp("2016-10-30 02:00+02:00", tz="Europe/Brussels") + pd.DateOffset(days=1))
2016-10-31 02:00:00+01:00
```